# Browser compatibility issue: Throwing off layout in Firefox & IE

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out what keeps throwing off the positioning of my navigation menu on a site I'm working on. I have added an image just below my menu to accentuate it, which displays perfectly in Chrome.... however the div expands and locates itself below the logo in Firefox and IE. I've tried and tried and just can't seem to figure it out. If I eliminate the image it works perfectly, but with it... not so much.

Example: http://espritduvin.ca/ (View in different browsers to witness my issue)

Answer (score 1):

Give your floating containers a width, e.g. 320px for the left container, 633 for the right one.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. If I eliminate the image all together it works fine.... can't figure it out.

Comment: hmm... I did it in ie11 via F12 console and it solved the problem.. i gave #header-right-section 633px and #header-left-section 320px, although the right-section is the more important one.

Comment: Update: depending on your screen width i see the surrounding div changes its width. So you probably want to use a % value for width, but just use a width, it will work.

Comment: That does work.... however, now when I size down the window my toggle menu resizes to the percentage I've keyed in - very small.

Comment: Yeah well you will need to change your layout at some point if you want to keep it responsive. When I resize the window in chrome, at some point the navigation will fall below the logo which is only natural when there is not enough space.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the image float:right, at the moment it's not given any css at all.

Comment: That sorts out the image, places it to the right underneath the menu, but doesn't push my menu back up towards the top as it appears in Chrome.

Comment: @user3737700 I assumed the image's position was making the div too wide pushing it down. I'll have another look at your css.

Comment: @user3737700 What positioning are you using on the nav holder? Could it be a width issue on IE, making the logo or navholder a few pixels tinner could fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is rendering a `clear` on the `header-right-section`.  Change the style for both left (logo) and right sections (nav bar) of the header to `display: inline-block`.

And I would suggest using Bootstrap for CSS in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try to put proper width to `header-right-section`, i think it will work. Right now there is only `float` value.
If you are using bootstrap, you can put this right and left in 2 columns.